# Show that sequence of subspaces becomes stationary

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

**Question:** Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb F$-vector space and $T:\ V\to V$ linear. Now we define $W_0:=V$ and $W_{i+1}:=T(W_i)$ for $i\in\mathbb N_0$. Show that there exists an $m\in\mathbb N$ such that $W_{m+i}=W_m$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$.

**My take:**  First I show that $W_{i+1}$ is a subspace of $W_i$. Let $v,w\in W_{i+1}$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb F$. Then there must exist $v',w'\in W_i$ such that $T(v')=v$ and $T(w')=w$. Since $W_i$ is a subspace (images are subspaces) we have $v'+\lambda w'\in W_i$ and thus $W_{i+1}\ni T(v'+\lambda w')=T(v')+\lambda T(w')=v+\lambda w$.

Now the rank–nullity theorem yields $$\dim(V)=\dim(\operatorname{range}(T))+\dim(\ker(T))$$ which is the same as $$\dim(W_0)=\dim(W_1)+\dim(\ker(T)).$$
Now, if $\dim(T)=0$ the proof is finished, because $W_1$ is a subspace of $W_0$ (as proven above) with the same dimension and thus is equal to $W_0$.

If $\dim(\ker(T))>0$ we have $\dim(W_0)>\dim(W_1)$. Now I use the same argument for $W_1$. The rank–nullity theorem yields $$\dim(W_1)=\dim(W_2)+\dim(\ker(T\mid_{W_1})).$$ So by the same logic the sequence becomes stationary here or we have $\dim(W_1)>\dim(W_2)$. Since $\dim(V)<\infty$ we can't decrease in dimension forever and thus the sequence must be stationary at some point.

Is this correct? Is there a cleaner way to write this down?

Comment: The idea is right! You might want to elaborate more about why $\dim(V) < \infty$ means that you can't decrease in dimension forever, or just make it more precise

Comment: @OsamaGhani If $\dim(V)=n$ then $\dim(\ker(T))>0$ can happen at most $n$ times, right?

Comment: Yup that's right

Comment: So does one need to formally prove this with induction or is it alright as of now?

Comment: It's up to you! You shouldn't need to use induction. You can simply say that if $w_i = \dim(W_i)$ then $w_i$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of integers, and so is unbounded, but the sequence is bounded below by $0$ (min dimension of a vector space) which is a contradiction.